# How to split an arraylist into multiple arraylist of equal sizes?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

thank you in advance for your attention.
I'll explain my situation, I need to separate an arraylist into multiple arraylist.
For example, I need to make requests for an api, in which I can only pass 50 items. Sometimes I need to query more than 50 items, so I need to make 2 requests for api, each with 50 items. Another situation would be, an array with 120 items, I would then need to make 3 requests, in the first 2 I pass 50 items, and in the third and last I would spend the last 20, so I would like to split this main arraylist with 120 items in 3 arrayslist, 2 with size of 50, and the third with size of 20. Below is the code I am using to do this but I am not succeeding, I would like to know a better solution for this. Thank you!

```
private ArrayList<String> idsVideos = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> testeTrab = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> videosArrays= new ArrayList<>();    

 for (int i =0; i < idsVideos.size(); i++){

                        if (testeTrab.size() ==  50) {
                            videosArrays.add(testeTrab);
                            testeTrab.clear();
                        }
                        testeTrab.add(idsVideos.get(i));
                        idsVideos.remove(i);
                    }


                    if (testeTrab.size() > 0  && videosArrays.size() > 0) {
                        videosArrays.add(testeTrab);       
                        testeTrab.clear();

                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the lists won't be modified then you don't need to create an `ArrayList<String>` for each chunk of data as `List<E>` support the convenience method `List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` which returns a "slice" of the original list.

This means that `idsVideos.subList(0,50)` will return a list containing the first `50` elements. Now you just need to take elements 50 by 50 until reaching last which will be just partial if `idsVideos.size()%50 != 0`.

```
final int CHUNK_SIZE = 50;

for (int i = 0; i < idsVideos.size(); i += CHUNK_SIZE) {
  List<String> chunk = idsVideos.subList(i, Math.min(i + CHUNK_SIZE, idsVideos.size()));
  ..
}
```

Comment: Hey Jack, thank you very much, this was exactly what I wanted, worked perfectly and met all my needs, thank you genius!